# IDesignTimeDbContextFactory not called

Tags: c#

I try to implement IDesignTimeDbContextFactory
I have TestContextFactory at the same namespace as Context.
But CreateDbContext was never called. I try to delete my db and run the project but during all migrations, this function was not called.

```
public class TestContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<TestContext>
    {
        public TestContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
        {
            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=.\;Database=db;Trusted_Connection=True;",
                opts => opts.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(90).TotalSeconds));

            return new TestContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
        }
    }
```